# How to recognize Event with onSensorChanged by comparing two float values

Tags: c#, xamarin, sensors

I want to read data from my Accelerometer Sensor and compare them if the first number of the float changes. I have some problem to unregister the listener or pause in order to compare and see if the average/Note has increased by a full Int for example "Note: 5.677" increases to "Note:6.234" then it supposed to be recognized as an event.

I have converted them into Ints so I can check if they are equal or not.
I already have tried to delay it with Thread.Sleep and pause but doesnt work.
Maybe because of Lock(_synlock) ?

```
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                avg = e.Values.Average();
                _sensorTextView.Text = string.Format("x={0:f}, y={1:f}, z={2:f}", e.Values[0], e.Values[1], e.Values[2]);
                _sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", avg);
                note1 = e.Values.Average();

                //Thread.Sleep(500);
                //base.OnPause();
                //_sensorManager.UnregisterListener(this);
                //base.OnResume();
                //_sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer), SensorDelay.Ui);


                //_sensorTextView.Text = string.Format("x={0:f}, y={1:f}, z={2:f}", e.Values[0], e.Values[1], e.Values[2]);
                //avg = e.Values.Average();
                //_sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", avg);
                //note2 = e.Values.Average();
            }
            int noteInt1 = Convert.ToInt32(note1);
            int noteInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(note2);

            //Thread.Sleep(2000); "zeige alle 2 sekunden an" 
            List<double> eventnumbers = new List<double> { };
            if (noteInt1 != noteInt2)
                {
                avg = e.Values.Average();       
                //Console.WriteLine("bye");
                _sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", avg);
                //foreach(SensorEvent e){
                eventnumbers.Add(new double()); //Value of avg is the value of the eventnumber element
                eventnumbers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                }

            }
```

UPDATE :

```
 public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                _sensorTextView.Text = string.Format("x={0:f}, y={1:f}, y={2:f}", e.Values[0], e.Values[1], e.Values[2]);
                //_sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", e.Values.Average());
                avg = e.Values.Average();
            }
            eventCounter();
        }
        public void eventCounter()
        {

            eventnumbers.Add(avg);          //add number to our buffer
            Console.WriteLine(avg);

            eventnumbers.Add(avg+1);       //adding a number different of our first one to see if the method works    
            Console.WriteLine(avg+1);



            while (eventnumbers.Count >= 1)     //as long as two elements included
            {
                for (int puffer = 0; puffer <= 10; puffer++)    //buffer of 10 Elements
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < eventnumbers.Count; i++)    //compare first number of our buffer
                    {
                        note1 = eventnumbers[i];    //remember value of first element
                        Console.WriteLine(note1);
                        Console.WriteLine("i ist:" + i);


                        for (int j = 1; j <= eventnumbers.Count; j++)   //with the second number of our buffer
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("j ist:" + j);
                            note2 = eventnumbers[j];    //remember value of second element
                            Console.WriteLine(note2);
                        }
                    }
                        while (eventnumbers.Count >= 1) //as long as two elements included
                        {
                                try
                                {

                                    noteInt1 = Convert.ToInt32(note1);  //double to Int 
                                    noteInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(note2);

                                    if (noteInt1 != noteInt2) //we parse to int in order to compare if event has changed
                                    {
                                        _sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", avg); //if yes update our displaying mark/number
                                        eventcounters.Add(avg);                     //add element to elementcounter

                                    }
                                    break;              //
                                }

                                catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)      //for the case if there are less than 2 elements to compare
                                {
                                    eventcounters.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);   //return all marks(numbers) from our eventcounter

                                }
                                break;
                            } break;

                        }

                    //throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
                eventnumbers.Clear();
            }
```

My Problem is that I do not get another (different) value when I call e.Value.Average(). I need to do it outside the method and call onSensorChanged another time but i dont know how to do that since I need to create another event, right? thats why I have used e1 and e2 but I think I miss something with the initialization i guess.

This is how I have tried so far creating two events:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, ISensorEventListener
    {
        static readonly object _syncLock = new Object();
        SensorManager _sensorManager;
        TextView _sensorTextView;
        TextView _sensorTextView2;
        double note1;
        double note2;
        double avg;
        SensorEvent e1;
        SensorEvent e2;
```

my one create():

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            _sensorManager = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(SensorService);
            _sensorTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.accelerometer_text);
            _sensorTextView2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.accelerometer_note);
            e1 = (SensorEvent)GetSystemService(ISensorEventListener);
            e2 = (SensorEvent)GetSystemService(ISensorEventListener);
            displayMark();
```

ISensorEventListener is marked a wrong btw

```
public void displayMark()
        {

            OnSensorChanged(e1);
            note1 = e1.Values.Average();

            OnSensorChanged(e2);
            note2 = e2.Values.Average();


            int noteInt1 = Convert.ToInt32(note1);
            int noteInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(note2);
            Console.WriteLine(noteInt1);
            Console.WriteLine(noteInt2);

            List<double> eventnumbers = new List<double> { };
            if (noteInt1 != noteInt2)
            {
                avg = e2.Values.Average();
                Console.WriteLine("bye");
                _sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", avg);
                //foreach(SensorEvent e){
                eventnumbers.Add(new double()); //Value of avg is the value of the eventnumber element
            }
            eventnumbers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to deal with the general approach here. Rather than trying to wait in an event for some new data I would use the events to record a value and then compare the new one to the last one. So outside the function would be a variable something like:

```
private int previousValue;
```

Then when the function is called it compares the 'new' value to this previous one:

```
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
{
    // Can't tell if this is required with information available
    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        // Capture the 'new' data to a local variable
        var newValue = e.Values.Average();

        if (newValue != previousValue)
        {
            // Value has changed by required amount so do something here
        }

        // Update the previous so next we we use this as our reference value
        previousValue = newValue;
}
```

This isn't a full solution but should be a better starting point for developing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg ! This is what I was also trying after my post haha. Im gonna try your version now.

Comment: I have made an update which is from yesterday and as you can see I have tried to compare two values but much complexer with lots of loops and a buffer. How do I create another event like e1 and e2 ? Im pretty new in Xamarin and not the fittest when it comes to programmimg.

Comment: From the code I can see I would expect `OnSensorChanged` to be assigned as a handler to something that is emitting events e.g. `Component.OnSensorChange += OnSensorChange`. Then I would expect that component to be regularly sending out these events, that is, repeatedly calling the `OnSensorChange` function with the latest value. If that's happening then the `_sensorTextView2.Text = string.Format("Note: {0}", avg);` line should be regularly updating the UI. Can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: Ok, there's some odd looking code here but based on the update it looks like you have a misunderstanding of how the events work. It would probably be worth reading something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/ to get a better understanding. Making some huge assumptions perhaps the line `e1 = (SensorEvent)GetSystemService(ISensorEventListener)` is getting a component that you can listen to events from? If that _was_ the case then `e1.OnSensorChange += OnSensorChange` would be the way forward.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Yeah you are right I am not really sure how this event method works, I will def have a look to it. But also I am not trying to compare two events anymore since your version is much more simple and short. I have another issue tho which is described in detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470816/how-do-i-delay-my-sensorlistener-in-onsensorchangedsensorevent-e-method